# How does the recursion unfolds in coin changing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I know there are tonnes of editorials and blogs explaining this but there is one common point where i am getting stuck.

Considering the recursion given below:

```
coin_change(coins,i,N) = coin_change(coins,i-1,N) + coin_change(coins,i-1,N-val[i])
```

Now this seems pretty straightforward which i think says that either we exclude the coin or we include it and solve the problem for remaining sum.

But my doubt is since there is infinite supply of coins, we can take as many coins as possible to achieve the sum, so how are we incorporating that thing in the recursive solution?

Also i am not able to understand the base cases for this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a binary tree, where the right branch searches subtracting the same coin again and again and the left branch searches all the other coins.

Take the simple case of N = 3 and coins = {1, 2}:
The right hand branch would be:

```
{1,2}: 1->1->1  (1,1,1)
  {2}:  ->2     (1,2)
```

The left hand branch would be:

```
{2}:    2->X    (No solution)
```

Would give the same result if 2 was the first coin:
Right hand branch:

```
{2,1}: 2->X     (No solution)
  {1}   ->1     (2,1)
```

Left hand branch:

```
{1}:   1->1->1  (1,1,1)
```

Note 1: you shouldn't have `-1` on the second call:

```
coin_change(coins,i,N) = coin_change(coins,i-1,N) + coin_change(coins,i,N-val[i])
```

Note 2: this isn't dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

If there is infinite supply of coins, then given condition allows to exclude whole nominal of coins. For example, no more nickels in solution. `val` array could look as `[1,5,10,25...]`

Note that problem with limited number of coins is slightly more complex - we have to organize array with repeated values `[1,1,1,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,...]` or use array of counters for every coin nominal `[1:3; 5:0; 10:12; ...]`.